# SVN - Trying to get a previous revision of a file but it keeps getting deleted

Tags: svn

I have a file in my svn repo that I want to get a previous revision of. I delete the file and then do an update using

```
svn update -r 'revision_ number' 'file_path'
```

I get the following message:

```
Restored 'file_path'
D 'file_path'
```

SVN apparently gets the file and then deletes it. This happens with any revision number other than the most recent.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening here?

Comment: Did the file actually exist in earlier revisions? Try updating to the latest and running `svn log filename`.

Comment: I can't believe it but you were right, I was accidentally entering the wrong revision number. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maby deleteing .svn folder in directory with file (send changes before if you have some) will help. After delete try:

```
svn co https://repository.com/name/trunk/path/to/folder/with/deleted/svn .

svn update -r 'revision_ number' 'file_path'
```

Maby this file was not present in this revision `svn log path/to/file` ?

Comment: I'm actually getting the same behaviour that I described in the question no matter which file, or directory, that I use. I tried deleting the folder that contained the file I was concerned with and updating the whole folder to a previous revision, and svn updated and then deleted that folder.

Comment: Destroying the metadata about your working copy is a very dangerous workaround. Better to understand what it is doing.

Comment: You were right about the file not being present in the revision. I was dyslexically reversing two number in the revision number.

Comment: Don't know why I get -1 because when everything fails this method usually works. Just need to remember to copy local changes somewere else when doing checkout. Metadata won't be lost because after checkout it will be recreated.

Comment: That makes sense to me. I accepted the answer, because it does contain the actual solution to what my problem was. I also didn't have any uncommitted changes in my local copy, so there wouldn't have been any issue with deleting the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't committed the change you can simply achieve this by using:

```
svn revert FileName
```